# Can't open second file using open() system call

Tags: c, file, unix, system-calls

I am trying to read a file, save it's content in two arrays (one for pair and the other for odd elements) and then write the content of my two arrays in two different files. I am using a menu with switch statements. First option should write the content of the two arrays in the two files, but I am getting an error opening the files I need to write on. I can open my first file and save it's content in the arrays, but can't seem to open (and write) on the other two files.

EDIT: I used perror to see what the error was and it is returning: Permission denied

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(){

    char buffer[100];
    int abrir;
    ssize_t bytes;
    int i = 0;

    char pares[5];
    char nones[5];

    int opcion;
    int archivoPares, archivoNones, reconstruido;

    abrir = open("holamundo.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if(abrir == -1){
            printf("Error opening file\n");
            return 1;
    }


    bytes = read(abrir, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
    if(bytes == -1){
            printf("Error reading file");
    }

    if((close(abrir))==-1){
            printf("Error closing file\n");
    }


    int par=0,non=-1;
    for(i; i<bytes; i++){
            if(i==0){
                    pares[par]=buffer[i] ;
            }
            else if(i%2 == 0){
                    par++;
                    pares[par]=buffer[i];
            }else{
                    non++;
                    nones[non]=buffer[i];
            }
    }


    printf("Enter an option: \n");
    scanf("%i",&opcion);
    int tamano;
    char mostrar[10];

    switch(opcion){
 case 1:
                  archivoPares = open("archivoPares.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT,0640);
                    printf("Desc : %d",archivoPares);//this gives me -1
                    write(archivoPares, pares, 6);
                    printf("Pares escrito\n");
                    close(archivoPares);
                    archivoNones = open("archivoNones.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
                    write(archivoNones, nones, 6);
                    printf("Nones escrito\n");
                    close(archivoNones);  
                    break;
            case 2:
                    read("archivosNones.txt", mostrar, sizeof(mostrar));
                    printf("los pares son %s\n", mostrar);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    read("archivosNones.txt", mostrar, sizeof(mostrar));
                    break;
            case 4:
                    reconstruido = open("reconstruido.txt",  O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
                    par=0;
                    non=-1;
                    i=0;
                    for(i; i<bytes; i++){
                            if(i==0){
                                    write(reconstruido, pares[0], 1);
                            }
                            else if(i%2 == 0){
                                    par++;
                                    write(reconstruido, pares[par], 1); 
                            }else{
                                    non++;
                                    write(reconstruido, nones[non], 1); 
                            }
                    }
                    close(reconstruido);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("\nExit\n");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("Error in input\n");
                    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: check return value of `open` and use `perror` to figure out what the error is. if you don't have write permissions in the current dir, that's what you would get.

Comment: Open returns -1, and the error is Permission denied. Is it because I created the files before?

Comment: `archivoPares = open("archivoPares.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT,0640)`. That will fail for other users than the one who ran the code the first time (when the file didn't exist)

Comment: `read()` takes an `int` as the first argument.

Comment: @考えネロク you are right. Didn't noticed until now. Should be the file descriptors. Thank you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That would be actually with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst many other problems, it is missing the header files for; `read()`  `close()`  `write()`

Comment: regarding: `for(i; i<bytes; i++){` the first parameter has not effect.;  The statement should be: `or(  ; i<bytes; i++ ){

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `unistd.h`

First, the prototypes of both `read()` and `write()` are in the `unistd.h` header, so you need to include it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

---

#### Issues with `read()`

The `read()` system call expect a *file descriptor* (i.e.: `int`) as the first argument. However, you are passing a *literal string*. Your intention seem to be clear, in:

```
read("archivosNones.txt", mostrar, sizeof(mostrar));
```

you mean to read `sizeof(mostrar)` bytes from the file `arhivosNones.txt`.

In order to achieve that, you need to first open that file by means of `open()` and then pass the obtained *file descriptor* to `read()`.

---

#### Issues with `write()`

The `write()` system call expects a `void *` (i.e.: any pointer type will do) as the second argument, but your are passing `pares[0]`, `pares[par]` and `nones[non]` which are of type `char`. You have to pass their addresses instead, i.e.: `&pares[0]`, `&pares[par]`, `&nones[non]`, which are of type `char *` (they will convert to `void *`).

Also, you are writing 6 bytes (i.e.: thrid argument to `write()`), but you have at most 5 bytes stored in `pares` and `nones`, so it should be 5 instead.

---

#### Issues with `open()`

The following call to `open()` won't work if the file `"archivoNones.txt"` doesn't exist:

```
archivoNones = open("archivoNones.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

I think you want instead a similar parameterization to the previous `open()` call:

```
archivoPares = open("archivoPares.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0640);
```

---

With all that in mind, your code would look like:

```
case 1:
    archivoPares = open("archivoPares.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT,0640);
    printf("Desc : %d",archivoPares);//this gives me -1
    write(archivoPares, pares, 5);
    printf("Pares escrito\n");
    close(archivoPares);
    archivoNones = open("archivoNones.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0640);
    write(archivoNones, nones, 5);
    printf("Nones escrito\n");
    close(archivoNones);  
    break;
case 2:
    archivoNones = open("archivoNones.txt", O_RDONLY);
    read(archivoNones, mostrar, sizeof(mostrar));
    printf("los pares son %s\n", mostrar);
    break;
case 3:
    archivoNones = open("archivoNones.txt", O_RDONLY);
    read(archivoNones, mostrar, sizeof(mostrar));
    break;
```